# Writing in xml does not keep the formatting?

Tags: c#, xml, formatting

I have this string :

```
<test>I am a test</test>
```

But when I write it in my xml file, and open it, I have this :

```
&lt;test&gt;I am a test&lt;/test&gt;
```

I don't know how to use the good formatting. I tried HttpUtility.HtmlDecode, but it does not solve my problem.

Do you have an idea on this ?

Edit : Sorry for not having posted my code before, I thought my problem was really really trivial. Here is a sample I just wrote that resumes the situation (I'm not at work anymore so I don't have the original code) :

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<root>" +
            "<test>I am a test</test>" +
            "</root>");
string content = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild.InnerXml;

XDocument saveFile = new XDocument();
saveFile = new XDocument(new XElement("settings", content));
saveFile.Save("myFile.xml");
```

I just want my xml file content looks like my original string,
so in my case the file would normally contain :

```
<settings>
    <root>
        <test>I am a test</test>
    </root>
</settings>
```

Right ? But instead, I have something like :

```
<settings>&lt;root&gt;&lt;test&gt;I am a test&lt;/test&gt;&lt;/root&gt;
</settings>
```

Comment: Where's the code that writes the xml file?

Comment: You don't actually have a problem.  Text in an XML file must be XML-escaped.

Comment: it's working like you coded it, but where is that?

Comment: Please show the full XML file of how it currently looks and how you expect it to look.

Comment: Should have closed as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179173/append-xml-string-block-to-existing-xmldocument...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something along the lines of [Converting XDocument to XmlDocument and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508572/converting-xdocument-to-xmldocument-and-vice-versa) to convert the root element of your `XmlDocument` to an `XElement` and then add it to your `XDocument`:

```
public static class XmlDocumentExtensions
{
    public static XElement ToXElement(this XmlDocument xmlDocument)
    {
        if (xmlDocument == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("xmlDocument");

        if (xmlDocument.DocumentElement == null)
            return null;

        using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDocument.DocumentElement))
        {
            return XElement.Load(nodeReader);
        }
    }        
}
```

And then use as follows:

```
        // Get legacy XmlDocument
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml("<root>" +
                    "<test>I am a test</test>" +
                    "</root>");

        // Add its root element to the XDocument
        XDocument saveFile = new XDocument(
            new XElement("settings", xmlDoc.ToXElement()));

        // Save
        Debug.WriteLine(saveFile.ToString());
```

And the output is:

> ```
> <settings>
>   <root>
>     <test>I am a test</test>
>   </root>
> </settings>
> ```

Note this avoids the overhead of converting the `XmlDocument` to an XML string and re-parsing it from scratch.

Comment: You saved me. Thank you !