# Insert a RootNode in an XML using C# XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I have a string in `XML` format returned by a without `RootNode` as follows:

```
<Node1 Id = "1" Value = "a"/>
<Node2 Id = "2" Value = "b"/>
<Node3 Id = "3" Value = "c"/>
```

Now, what I want is to embed the returned string in a root node, for example

```
<XML>
   <Node1 .... />
   <Node2 .... />
</XML>
```

how can I do this using `System.Xml` namespace (`XmlDocument`, ecc..) ?

I have following code:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument(); 
xml.Loadxml(stringWithoutRoot);
```

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** ok sorry I was unclear. My real problem is this. I have a lot of methods doing practically the same thing, the only thing that changes is the name of the stored procedure that must be executed. So what I want to do to make the code more readable is to create only one method and pass the name of the stored procedure as its input parameter. I think this is more logic.

Second issue: I noticed that some stored procedures return an xml with root node and others don't so my solution is to pass also the XML as input parameter.

An example invoking,

```
executeSqlCommand(mySP, "<XML></XML>)
```

will put the result of the stored procedure in the XML as follows

```
<XML>resultFromSPWithoutRootNode</XML>
```

so I need something like this

```
string result = ..... // some operation in DB

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rootXMl))   // where rootXML is my second parameter
{
    append the result to the root node rootXML
}
```

The append way is missing.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I've no code. What I do: XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument(); xml.Loadxml(stringWithoutRoot); I don't know how to append my sting to a root node.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like that ?

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
string nodesString = "<node/>" ;
xml.LoadXml("<root>" + nodesString+ "</root>");
```

Comment: Thank you Jérôme for your tip. Please see my EDIT to better understand my question. I need something like this: xml.LoadXml(rootNode); xml.Append(restOfXml)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to use `XmlDocumentFragment` like suggested here:

[Append XML string block to existing XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179173/append-xml-string-block-to-existing-xmldocument)

Thank you